# Default argument if default constructible

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I have a small problem, my code works but it's not ideal.

I have a function that takes a predicate as parameter. I want to support these syntax:

```
myClass.foo([](auto param){ return true; }); // predicate sent as parameter
myClass.foo<PredicateType>(); // predicate type sent as template argument
myClass.foo(); // default predicate took
```

However, in order to do this, I have duplicated the function like this:

```
struct MyClass {
    template<typename Predicate = DefaultPredicate&&, std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<detail::decay_t<Predicate>>::value, int> = 0>
    void foo(Predicate&& p = std::decay_t<Predicate>{}) {
        // stuff...
    }

    template<typename Predicate, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_default_constructible<detail::decay_t<Predicate>>::value, int> = 0>
    void foo(Predicate&& p) {
        // exact same stuff...
    }
};
```

Is there a way to do this without duplicating my code?
The ideal would be to have one function. How can I do this, preferably in c++11?

Comment: put `stuff...` in a function and call it twice ?

Comment: well, creating yet another function would work, but i'd like to see if it's possible to squeeze this in one function.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing the need for that `enable_if`. Default function arguments are only instantiated when actually used.

Comment: Thinking about it I'm not sure either

Comment: You really want to call it like `myClass.foo<PredicateType>();`? Why not `myClass.foo(PredicateType{});` instead? The design would become simpler, and you seem to loose nothing.

Comment: Yes. Originally, it was not a templated function, so picking a default predicate is required in order to not break existing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just strip out the pointless SFINAE and the equally pointless `decay`:

```
struct MyClass {
    template<typename Predicate = DefaultPredicate>
    void foo(Predicate&& p = Predicate{}) {
        // stuff...
    }    
};
```

Default function arguments are instantiated separately, and only when they are actually required.

Comment: Oh! That's new to me, did't know default arguments was instantiated separately. Does that mean the compiler will sfinae out the function if `Predicate` is not default constructible or it will be an hard error?

Comment: Good to know. I will try to make it more sfinae friendly, since this function is part of my public API.

Comment: I guess we need more clarity on what "immediate context" means?

Comment: @T.C.: Can you demonstrate how it is SFINAE-friendly in GCC? On my tests, it looks like even GCC treats it as hard error: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fHMKlK1rXGMtmEH1

Comment: @Andrzej Hmm, I can't reproduce it either - probably misread something. I think what I saw was different behavior when fed something like this: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iUdLhpZjdyXnsTjD -  but GCC just ignores the error entirely rather than SFINAE.

Comment: Interesting. The behaviour seems to vary from example to example.

Answer (score 4):

Just make a template function taking no arguments and forward to the function taking a predicate:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Predicate {};
struct DefaultPredicate {};
struct MyClass {
    template<typename Predicate>
    void foo(Predicate&& p) {
        std::cout << "Stuff\n";
    }

    template<typename Predicate = DefaultPredicate>
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Forward ";
        foo(Predicate{});
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass my;
    my.foo<>(); // DefaultPredicate
    my.foo<DefaultPredicate>();
    my.foo<Predicate>();
    my.foo(Predicate());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel quite stupid right now, This answer is so simple! Argh!